# Can I change out my 10-speed Ultegra 6600 group set with Mavic R-SYS wheels with a 12 speed?

Tags: compatibility, groupsets

I was thinking of replacing the group set on my Serotta Nove (2006) with a 12-speed Sensah Pro. I am not sure that is feasible. I am currently using the original Ultegra (I think 6600) which needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

The Mavic wheels will be fine with current shimano road groups: they are 11speed compatible. This means the Sensah group will work IF the cassette is designed for shimano HG spline.